# Generating random numbers while being blind to the method

Tags: distributions, random-generation

Let's say you needed to generate a set of random numbers while having no idea how the numbers are generated or what the underlying distribution is. Maybe you're testing out a process that fits a variety of distributions to a set of data, and can't have pre-knowledge of the mean, standard deviation, or which distribution the random data belongs to.

Typing

```
rnorm(20,mean=3,sd=2)
```

into R gives you 20 random numbers from a normal distribution with mean 3 and sd 2. So you know what the mean and sd of the sample ought to be.

You can kick the can a bit further down the road by typing

```
rnorm(20 , mean=rnorm(1,mean=0,sd=2) , sd=rlnorm(1,mean=1,sd=1))
```

Now you don't know what the mean and sd are but you have a decent idea of where they could be. (in the example above, there's 95% chance of the mean falling between -4 and 4). *Furthermore, you still know it's going to be a normal distribution*

---

You can take this further by randomly using different distributions. A code example in R might be:

```
generate_random_dist <-function(n,a,b){

k <-sample(1:5,1)   #picks a random number between 1 and 5

if(k == 1){
    rnorm(n,a,b)    # randomly chosen from the normal distribution, with mean=a and sd=b 
} else if (k == 2){
    runif(n,a,b)    # uniform distribution between a and b
} else if (k == 3){
    rlnorm(n,a,b)   # lognormal distribution with log-mean=a and log-sd=b
} else if (k == 4){
    rpois(n,lambda=a)   # poisson distribution with lambda=a
} else {
    rt(n,b) + a     # t - distribution with b degrees of freedom and centre a
    }
}

A <-rnorm(1,mean=3,sd=4)
B <-rlnorm(1)

generate_random_dist(50,2,2)
```

This is better, but still not truly ideal, as I've only chosen from one of 5 methods to generate them, and I know the odds of getting a Poisson distribution are 1 in 5 and the odds of getting an exponential distribution are nil because I didn't code it in.

Furthermore, most real life data don't fit neatly into a given distribution as the process that generates such data is much more complex and less mathematically pure than the processes behind the canonical distributions.

**How can I write a method for the generation of random numbers where I have as little prior information about their generation as possible? Is such a feat even possible? Or is the best approach to get someone else to do it and have them not tell you how they generated those numbers?**

Comment: Perhaps use real data? Say draw a random [time-series](https://datasetsearch.research.google.com/search?query=time-series).

Comment: "you still know it's going to be a normal distribution" is not correct: marginally the sample is neither Normal nor iid.

Comment: @Xi'an Maybe if each individual point is generated with a different mean and sd. But if you check the code, they're all generated with the same (random) mean and sd.

Comment: And to the close voter, what further detail or clarity does this need?

Comment: @Xi'an I am struggling to follow your comment, and I wonder if it's a flaw in my wording. Is it incorrect to say a sample of a normal distribution is normal?

Comment: Do you understand the meaning of _marginal_ in my sentence? The _marginal_ distribution of the sample is$$\int \prod_{i=1}^n \varphi(x_i;\mu,\sigma)\,\pi(\mu,\sigma)\text{d}(\mu,\sigma)$$

Comment: A simpler but analogous question is "is there any general way to choose a number to represent some quantity in a study."  Obviously not--it has to depend on the study.  Likewise there is no general answer to the question of drawing numbers randomly without any other information.

Comment: No, such a feat is not possible, and for epistemiological reasons rather than because of any mathematical difficulty. The whole point of generating random numbers is to simulate a specific random process in order to test the consequences. If you can't specify a target distribution then you haven't defined what you mean by "random" and hence you can't generate random numbers. You are perhaps assuming that all randomness becomes the same after inputing enough choices, but it doesn't. You always have to specific the probabilities of the unknown states or possibilities.

Comment: My previous comment is a longer way to make the same point that whuber did, somewhat more succinctly (and which I upvoted). Together I hope we have got the idea across.

Comment: @GordonSmyth Please if you have an answer, give it as an answer. There is too much answering-in-comments on this SE as it is.  In regards to my question, I'm not trying to generate 'the most randomest ever' dataset. Indeed, in the example above, some runs would produce a very tight cluster of points. I'm after a data generation process that has the propensity to *surprise*. In my line of work, datasets from the real world are often messy and unruly, especially if they involve human input, and *especially* when some of those humans are deliberately and maliciously messing with the system.

Comment: There have been times where a few outliers were so far out of whack, that I had to use a log(log()) graph to adequately visualise them. And I have to make sure my code is at least a little bit robust to such unexpected occurrences. I'm not asking about a data generation technique that can generate every crazy possible result, just something more capable of unexpected and surprising results than the rnorm() function.

Comment: @Ingolifs The reason for my comment was to prompt you to reconsider your question or to add more information so that a useful answer becomes possible. If you edit you question to say what you said to me (that you want normal-like data but with outliers) then someone will be able to show you how to do that. Ideally you should give some examples of the sort of outliers you see so that a responder can tune the type of outliers being generated. At the moment, you answer doesn't make sense as it is asking for something impossible, which makes it problematic to give a constructive answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is no general way to generate a set of pseudo-random numbers without specification of a method.  Any method you use is going to require you to stipulate what you are doing.  So, if you don't want to use real data, and you want to remain ignorant of the generating method, the most obvious solution to your problem is to **have someone else generate the pseudo-random numbers for your analysis**.  For example, here are $n=10^3$ pseudo-random numbers that I generated from a distribution that you would be highly unlikely to guess *a priori*:

```
1262.5, 425.4, 481.6, 1235.2, 678.6, 1245.2, 656, 588.6, 439.2, 
497.8, 1371.3, 616.2, 355.6, 1297.4, 412, 477.2, 593.7, 488.6, 
1385.2, 1364.3, 414.3, 359.6, 510, 1356.8, 371.3, 351, 1316.6, 
536.8, 646.8, 438, 347.1, 395.4, 527.4, 488.3, 543.6, 434.7, 
400.4, 418.6, 498, 631.4, 403.5, 1305.6, 644.7, 1350.2, 1392, 
658, 541.5, 367.2, 362.3, 525.9, 474, 487, 616.5, 1283.7, 1232.8, 
1339.6, 354.1, 489.7, 374.7, 667.5, 1329.2, 541.9, 570.3, 629.8, 
1307.9, 626.8, 1231.9, 527.1, 1363.5, 1249.3, 422.4, 525.7, 666.9, 
461.7, 1316.2, 1285.7, 371.6, 378.2, 470.3, 356.9, 453.9, 627.6, 
660, 1277.1, 1350.1, 635.3, 409, 613.2, 668.1, 383.5, 430.7, 
498.5, 345.2, 1291.7, 1306.7, 1276.5, 1374.1, 567.5, 677.9, 567.9, 
523.4, 516.4, 435, 618.3, 457.8, 1348.5, 418.3, 465.9, 402.5, 
531.1, 1375.5, 1242.2, 534.1, 620.4, 1346.5, 494.4, 524.7, 582.9, 
483, 540.9, 469.4, 1271.5, 656.3, 1248.5, 1346.3, 471, 404, 504.4, 
623.2, 380.9, 399.3, 375.4, 497, 525.7, 362.7, 494, 358.3, 1294.6, 
367.2, 531.2, 1366, 654.8, 383.1, 1275, 1391.4, 649.1, 463.2, 
383.1, 397.8, 474.7, 437.9, 1342.1, 459, 395.6, 1276.1, 528.2, 
362.9, 372.5, 1286.8, 1299.3, 350.3, 408, 451.9, 525.1, 503.5, 
494.1, 452.9, 629.1, 383.6, 1234.5, 593.9, 1307.3, 513.4, 354.1, 
1286.3, 1316.5, 489.3, 594.8, 1308.8, 472.1, 1311.7, 364.8, 611.4, 
651.8, 351, 1345.8, 556.4, 454, 1259.4, 470, 1268.7, 1368.5, 
449.5, 388.2, 485.5, 627.5, 371.4, 579.1, 475.3, 1242.9, 1346.1, 
458.4, 351.3, 1391.4, 588.9, 478.4, 544.7, 1335.2, 361.3, 637.5, 
381.6, 1230.3, 1376.4, 657.1, 344.2, 368.7, 427, 638.2, 374, 
449.5, 368, 1247, 456.9, 612.2, 1296.9, 1308.2, 398.4, 649.5, 
548.5, 1383.2, 1339.2, 1269.5, 1308.5, 507.9, 440, 636.5, 502.9, 
425.6, 346.6, 383.8, 1276.9, 456.1, 595.2, 1257.9, 364.6, 1325.4, 
535.3, 608, 494.2, 1316.1, 1272.1, 1291.9, 1332.8, 1387.6, 621.5, 
647.4, 482.1, 560.7, 1380.5, 560, 667.4, 405.7, 448.1, 1267.3, 
515.5, 1237.6, 488.1, 656.3, 486.2, 1387.1, 596.2, 388.8, 624.6, 
362.5, 522.1, 1334.1, 538.1, 368.1, 1318.9, 541.1, 1299.9, 451.3, 
1350, 406.9, 381.1, 1263, 559.2, 581.1, 419.1, 547.3, 436.8, 
451.6, 455.5, 1360.9, 1380.8, 1280.3, 382.7, 618.4, 460.1, 620.3, 
492.5, 390, 1389.6, 481.3, 452.2, 1267.3, 380.9, 387.4, 415.1, 
398.1, 1226.4, 351.3, 601, 358.7, 460, 484.1, 478.2, 675.6, 1339, 
1242.9, 1302.1, 526, 429.8, 1359.4, 607.7, 393.5, 1255.3, 542.9, 
667.9, 1286.4, 435.6, 486.5, 487.3, 629.5, 410.5, 429.1, 422.2, 
493.8, 1338, 438, 1244.3, 357.7, 635.2, 532.6, 626.5, 572.5, 
465.9, 507.5, 447.3, 635, 1291.4, 1255.1, 439.4, 1225.4, 489.8, 
416.7, 470.3, 635.2, 1323.4, 382.4, 590.6, 353.9, 432.4, 660.6, 
1245.6, 457.6, 377.6, 588.8, 426.8, 474.1, 634.3, 527.5, 1248.6, 
399.9, 379.1, 1324.6, 615.8, 1382.9, 652.1, 407.3, 476.9, 439.7, 
383.6, 625.1, 576.3, 1358, 404.8, 606.6, 517.4, 1368.7, 346.3, 
602.4, 530.1, 638.4, 637.5, 1242.8, 1301, 1325.5, 581.5, 435, 
549.6, 560.5, 345.7, 532.1, 383.6, 675, 1382.7, 551.2, 393.2, 
359.8, 1295.1, 589.4, 538.9, 589, 412.5, 586.7, 1354.5, 1360.1, 
586.7, 1373.6, 1328.2, 651.3, 600.6, 429.8, 510.4, 473.7, 419.1, 
1318.5, 1391.7, 511.2, 659.5, 573.7, 354.6, 512.8, 406.3, 1288.4, 
528, 538.8, 662, 508.3, 352.8, 601.7, 1354.4, 1341.6, 470.3, 
1304.9, 576.4, 1297.5, 349.3, 358.9, 606.5, 668.3, 1341.4, 615.1, 
482.8, 392.5, 552.8, 462.9, 1310.6, 669.1, 530.9, 1356.5, 493.2, 
558.8, 516.3, 1277.2, 378.9, 676.6, 1367.1, 405.4, 363, 363, 
367.5, 371.7, 1316.1, 1306.8, 371.2, 1253.8, 1240.1, 393.9, 1358.8, 
570.5, 475.2, 374, 623.2, 559.7, 565, 1368.9, 517.2, 1265.1, 
1271.8, 1361.1, 1289.5, 388.9, 1264.4, 1388.6, 1308.3, 625, 466.3, 
413.2, 393.5, 530.2, 614.5, 508.2, 383.1, 1339.6, 382.1, 588.9, 
367, 368.6, 579.4, 618.1, 1248, 531.2, 1294.2, 391, 593.9, 1234.5, 
391.3, 389.8, 622, 1262.9, 583.5, 557.9, 1226.3, 581.7, 439.1, 
1310.1, 407.6, 1338.4, 401, 1279.4, 384.1, 464.4, 382.1, 1368.6, 
505.7, 473.2, 1274.9, 485.4, 1266.8, 1335.5, 1310.8, 1394.9, 
350.9, 535.5, 491.2, 521.8, 560.1, 416.5, 636.2, 391, 1366.5, 
1269.8, 420.7, 652.9, 1392.3, 1382.3, 376.9, 1229.9, 358.5, 1279.5, 
415.3, 483.7, 627.9, 497.4, 368.5, 522.5, 547.4, 574.1, 544.2, 
1303.8, 462.2, 1254.9, 1382, 389.4, 400.1, 1340, 370.6, 595.1, 
539.6, 1280.6, 542.9, 1291.9, 566.1, 470, 375.4, 543.8, 449.6, 
1304.6, 564.3, 521.3, 541.2, 601.2, 589.6, 494.1, 582.2, 441.4, 
361.5, 1258.3, 367.9, 1301, 1225.5, 522.2, 493.2, 1336.4, 1283.4, 
1250.2, 449, 582.4, 441.4, 442, 440.2, 1241.9, 456.1, 400, 1341, 
1393.2, 1369, 407, 493.6, 349, 536.9, 353.5, 510.3, 414.2, 670.2, 
1366.2, 552.4, 1287.2, 1310, 383.5, 567.7, 404.4, 475.8, 345.3, 
587.9, 506.3, 659.5, 1275.2, 614.8, 1306.3, 1323.6, 1282.5, 528.3, 
382.4, 1300.1, 606.4, 596, 552.8, 1345.5, 1320, 394.7, 1279.5, 
1340.9, 356.6, 1284.4, 1370.3, 592.2, 405.2, 469.7, 448.2, 1264.1, 
565.4, 459.2, 405.5, 467.2, 526.6, 1371.9, 1228.4, 612.6, 609.1, 
475.3, 1300.3, 1350.2, 1373.9, 563.1, 402.1, 1300.5, 409.1, 1292.4, 
1393.9, 534.6, 440.6, 645.3, 572.8, 485, 1238.6, 1331.6, 679.3, 
1358, 608.4, 1355.8, 493.8, 367, 1315.8, 358.9, 679.5, 485.1, 
1310.8, 664.5, 574.8, 637.8, 353.9, 638.9, 1372.1, 636.9, 1345.3, 
377, 464.7, 663.8, 461.3, 662.1, 1243.6, 487.3, 1245.1, 473.4, 
589.6, 1233.3, 643, 602.9, 593.4, 1339.3, 369.2, 1331, 1391.7, 
398.3, 489.9, 475.1, 519.6, 1284.4, 557.2, 1340, 573.8, 434.3, 
399.8, 531.2, 571.2, 649.7, 1389.3, 660.2, 447.3, 1382.4, 1351.3, 
515.5, 671.4, 1311.9, 356.7, 377.4, 1310, 348.7, 679.7, 1352.2, 
578.3, 478.5, 503.4, 438, 595.5, 553.9, 525.2, 1294.3, 443, 1269.5, 
612.8, 1380.5, 558.8, 387.4, 1332.9, 382.9, 469.5, 437.6, 388.4, 
671.9, 421.7, 348.4, 472.8, 1301.2, 532.3, 614.1, 1372.4, 677.2, 
435.3, 458.9, 615.1, 658.9, 673.9, 462.2, 482.9, 490.7, 1265.5, 
1323.8, 433.3, 364.2, 461.7, 431, 603.4, 1284, 1365.7, 543.5, 
495.8, 1288.1, 365.4, 476.5, 538.8, 382.5, 355.4, 488.7, 1235.4, 
584.2, 1335.8, 666.6, 556.4, 409.1, 1292.2, 1370.7, 629.8, 569.7, 
1327.5, 516.8, 586.1, 574.9, 473.7, 599.1, 349.8, 481.6, 1315.1, 
351.2, 351.8, 1238, 646.6, 663.9, 1249.5, 633.5, 465, 1290, 512.3, 
1340.4, 513.6, 1250.6, 454.3, 624.2, 535.8, 500, 1253.7, 439, 
492.5, 1287.2, 1379, 1271.6, 463.7, 1273.7, 1365.6, 345.7, 1292.6, 
414.6, 461.8, 403.3, 653, 546.8, 632.8, 1239.5, 655.3, 398.6, 
588.3, 1342.3, 492.8, 514.4, 632.6, 415.9, 1237.7, 1358.8, 387.3, 
1375.8, 469.3, 1312.9, 345.4, 417.1, 1304.2, 1301.6, 498.7, 516.4, 
1332.4, 526.9, 659.7, 1321.6, 638.4, 418.8, 438, 355.2, 452.4, 
356.4, 520.5, 1341.7, 671.7, 584.7, 1236.4, 1334.6, 1358.3, 659.7, 
394.7, 1286.3, 1329.7, 353.8, 1383.2, 1264.8, 403.1, 438.9, 498.5, 
1354.7, 500, 525, 1282.7, 1268.5, 392.8, 364.6, 589.2, 658.2, 
556.9, 583.2, 427.2, 564, 387.9, 678.2, 396.2, 344, 561.1, 575.7, 
472.6, 1282.9, 1319.8, 369.5, 388.3, 395.4, 565.7, 547.9, 1383.8, 
423.2, 409.6, 565.7, 609, 566.3, 395.9, 402.4, 400.4, 1358.2, 
1323.7, 616.8, 1280.4, 628, 1250.1, 532.4, 449.5, 1366.1, 1249.8, 
640.7, 441.9, 412.8, 615.5, 1325.4, 427.8, 545.9, 483.5, 621.4, 
559.1, 489.9, 414.5, 1284.3, 656.3, 1245.8, 1266.2, 643.8, 541.3, 
435.9, 511, 651, 516.3, 552.9, 625.2, 513.7, 1371.8, 608.1, 351.5, 
1392.6, 451.2, 432.3, 425.4, 1254.6, 667.5, 361.5, 572, 1310.8, 
1296.2, 445.8, 1392.1, 1376, 635.6, 594, 433.6, 418.8, 1301.7
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the premise of your question, however how would you quantify the "surprise" as you put it.

Regardless, one naive solution you have allowed, from the two first examples you give, since you have defined the second method being "better" than the first, is simply a recursive call on nested `rnorm`'s. You can do this an arbitrary number of times through recursion to produce an unbounded descent of better models, since you have defined adding RV's to parameters of other RV's produces more of a "surprise".

As an example, check out this code:

```
generate_random_dist <- function(n, n_mean, n_sd, ln_mean, ln_sd){

    i <- 0
    chng_mean <- rnorm(1,n_mean,n_sd)
    chng_sd <- rlnorm(1, ln_mean, ln_sd)
    chng_mean_of_sd <- rlnorm(1, ln_mean, ln_sd) # we cannot use the normal mean 
                                                 # as it isn't necessarily > 0
                                                 # this solution just calls another lognorm
    while (i<n){

        chng_mean <- rnorm(1,chng_mean,chng_sd)                 # recursively generate new
        chng_mean_of_sd <- rlnorm(1,chng_mean_of_sd, chng_sd)   # means and sd's
        chng_sd <- rlnorm(1,chng_mean_of_sd, chng_sd)           # with previously generated
                                                                # random means and sd's
        i <- i + 1

    }

    return rnorm(1,chng_mean, chng_sd)    # returns an rnorm who's mean and sd
                                          # are RV's whose mean's and sd's
                                          # are RV's etc., up to n times.

}
```

I have simply made a recursive call of your "better" solution. You could extend this even further by applying it to all known distributions that are able to be sampled in `R`. Then sample through these distributions like in your third example, however again, "surprise" can always be increased simply by increasing the number of recursions.